# Find occurrences of a file of words in a dictionary

Tags: log-files, grep

I have a number of search logs that I want to compare against certain dictionary files.  Once I process the search logs to filter out certain entries and get all the search terms into separate lines, what is an easy way to figure out how many of the search terms are present in the dictionary file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take the preparation of input aside and assume these inputs:

Search log - one searched term on line, no repetition, something like this:

```
car
tramway
bus
train
skate
rollerblade
bike
```

Dictionary - one dictionary word on line, no repetition, something like this:

```
car
tramway
bus
train
bike
aeroplane
submarine
```

And if you want to select lines from search log, which are in dictionary, you can do it like this:

`grep -f dictionary search_log`

It'll return

```
car
tramway
bus
train
bike
```

And if you want number of these words just pipe it to `wc -l`

`grep -f dictionary search_log | wc -l`

And result will be 5.

Comment: +1 for `grep -f file`

Comment: The only problem with that is partial matches in `search_log` will be counted more than once.  Is there a way to only count exact matches?  Sorry, probably should've specified that in my question...

Comment: The -f parameter except file with regexp patterns, so line in dictionary can look like this `^bike$` which defines exact match.

Comment: Great, exactly what I needed.  Any tips on performance?  This takes really long.

Comment: I went thru manual and if you do `grep -x -f dictionary search_log` you don't have to surround words in dictionary with ^$ - grep will look for exact matches. That could help. Otherwise you can divide dictionary files and execute grep in more instances.